# Why is “Equal Rites” misspelled on two pages?

Tags: discworld

In the HarperTorch paperback of *Equal Rites* the title of the book is misspelled on the heading of two different pages as "Equal Rights” (I don’t have the book with me at the moment). This seems likely to just be an error, but knowing Pratchett, I’m wondering about whether this is some joke or point that I’ve missed. Does anyone know of a reason for this misspelling?

Comment: I’m not expecting any answers for this one

Comment: Misspelled where? In the title headers?

Comment: @Valorum yes, in the title headers on two pages early in the book. I’m just wondering whether anyone noticed any point for this, though I’m assuming that it was just a mistake of the publisher.

Comment: A very quick flick through my copy reveals no such typo, nor is it in the ebook version

Comment: @Valorum then it is probably just a mistake. Ah well

Comment: Well, this is a book about equal (gender) rights. Apparently somebody at HarperTorch did not realise that there was a pun in the title, I don't think it get's more mysterious than that.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10332/are-questions-about-physical-book-production-flaws-on-topic

Comment: Is it misspelt only on those two pages and all others are correct? In that case, I would assume some intention (or those headers actually being set manually).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes, it’s just two pages in the book.

Comment: I have a copy of Split Infinity where pages 57-88 have been replaced with pages 265-296.